# Reaction between NaOH and Carbonic acid

Tags: acid-base, reactivity

I was presented with the following reaction when we were just learning about acids and bases:

$$\ce{2NaOH + H2CO3 -> H2O + Na2CO3}$$
however I had thought it might've been something like

$$\ce{NaOH + H2CO3 -> H2O + NaHCO3}$$

They both seem to fit the notion of a neutralization reaction creating a salt so how do I know that the first one is correct? The second reaction looks fine to me (is it that bicarbonate is too reactive?) and more intuitive as the carbonic acid just gives a proton away ending up as an ion to bond with $Na$, so how do I distinguish between these kind of cases?

Answer (score 4):

You're right, both of these reactions take place.

From [Wikipedia, the Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonate)

> In aqueous solution, carbonate, bicarbonate, carbon dioxide, and carbonic acid exist together in a dynamic equilibrium.

Now, the answer to the question depends on context. If you're asked to do this reaction in a mildly acidic/weakly basic medium, then the answer would be the bicarbonate, while in a strongly basic medium, the answer would be the carbonate.

Interesting for further reading:

This $\ce{pH}$ dependent equilibrium between carbonate and bicarbonate is one of the ways in which the blood $\ce{pH}$, and the $\ce{pH}$ of the mouth is maintained. It also helps aquatic life to survive in ocean waters. (Also see urea cycle and carbon cycle)

Comment: @ AbhigyanC What about $\pu{pH}$ at the second equivalence point, more or less than 7?

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh $\ce{pK_{a1}}$ and $\ce{pK_{a2}}$ of carbonic acid are $4.5\times10^{-7}$ and $4.7\times10^{-11}$, respectively. So it happens at $\ce{pH}=8.34$, using the formula for pH of a amphiprotic anion is the average of the two pK values. See http://www.chembuddy.com/?left=pH-calculation&right=pH-amphiprotic-salt